# Laravel 4 with blade and subsections

Tags: templates, laravel-4, laravel-blade

It is possible to create subsection inside blade template on Laravel 4, like:

layouts/default.blade.php

```
<html>
 <head>
   @section('header')
   @show
 </head>
 <body>
   @yield('content')
 </body>
</html>
```

layouts/sidemenu.blade.php

```
@section('sidemenu')
 <div>
  ....
  @section('subsidemenu')
  <!-- user permission depend menu -->
  @show
 </div>
@show
```

layouts/header.blade.php

```
some header parameters
```

layouts/content.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts/default')
   @section('header')
   @parent
   @show
   @include('layouts/sidemenu.blade.php')
   @section('subsidemenu')
   @parent
   @show
@stop
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `layouts/content.blade.php` looks a bit messy or incomplete if you want. First you didn't define the "content" section itself. Also I would recommend to use "@stop" to close sections in child views and do not define sections from parent view if you are not intendin to modify it. Try something like this for `layouts/content.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts/default')

@section('content')
...
@include('layouts/sidemenu.blade.php')
...
@stop
```

And subsidemenu block could be included in sidemenu:

```
@section('sidemenu')
<div>
....
@section('subsidemenu')
<!-- user permission depend menu -->
@stop
</div>
@stop
```

Comment: OK, thanks for reply. I have one more question. Can I overwrite or call subside section inside content.blade.php. So I want to create more of contents file for admins, for moderators, for public, ... in separate direcorites (view/admins, view/moderators, view/public, ...) and I want to have only one 'base' side menu, and inside each of the content file (admins, moderators, users,...) I want to add user depend menu items. It is possible or maybe you have better idea?

Comment: Probably you cloud try `nest()` method. 
`$view = View::make('root.view')->nest('sidemenu', 'admins.sidemenu', $data);` and choose sidemenu view ('admins.sidemenu') in depends on user role.